# How make sql query "not in" more simply use only "join"?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Have query:

```
select a.id from selzde.elorder a
inner join selzde.elorder b on a.name = b.name 
    and a.workname = b.workname 
    and b.id = needId
where a.id not in (select id_elorder from selzde.drugselorder)
```

how make sql query `not in` more simply use only `join`?

Comment: Why is NOT IN not simple enough? A JOIN will be harder to read...

Comment: I'm wondering how much will cost `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.id from selzde.elorder a
inner join selzde.elorder b on a.name = b.name 
and a.workname = b.workname 
and b.id = needId
left outer join selzde.drugselorder d on a.id = d.id_elorder
where d.id_elorder is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Left join to `drugselorder`, on `id_elorder = a.id`, then choose the ones with no match (i.e. `where drugselorder is null`)... I wouldn't say it was any more "simple", though.

Comment: I was hoping that i can avoid the use of `where`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use MINUS operator rather than not in as follows:

```
select a.id 
from selzde.elorder a 
     inner join selzde.elorder b 
on a.name = b.name      
and a.workname = b.workname      
and b.id = needId 
MINUS
select id_elorder 
from selzde.drugselorder
;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Roger